# Reading distributed lucene indices through solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, distributed

I will explain my problem statement with the following illustration.

I have 4 machines, each running instances of my application which uses lucene for search. This means lucene indices have been created individually on all 4 machines and have been used internally for search using lucene in the respective instances.

Now, I am putting a server on top of all these 4 machines, so that it's search feature could aggregate all the results from individual instances and give me a result. Hope the problem statement is clear.

Now the question, I am aware solr can read indices created by lucene. Does this hold good even for a distributed search? Can solr just distribute the search over individually created lucene indices?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this is not possible, I ll just have to go and rewrite the individual instances with solr and create indices suitable for distributed search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the Lucene indexes from Solr using [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)
Solr does not do any additional handling of the indexed data during indexing.
So the Lucene indexes can be used by Solr, as long as the indexes are compatible.

There are some [limitations of Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch#Distributed_Searching_Limitations) which you would need to take into account when building the data.

Comment: Thank you @Jayendra especially for pointing out the limitations of distributed search. I actually wanted a date faceting and just realised solr doesn't support date faceted search in distributed mode! However with the help of the patch in Jira, I am able to do it. Thanks again!